# Not able to limit the memory usage with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am configuring ImageMagick for PSD thumbnail generation using the command [1]. It works perfectly for small size PSD but when processing a 2GB PSD, the server CPU and memory usage will keep increasing to 100% in a few minutes till the process is killed by the server.

The CPU and memory utilization could not be controlled by the configuration at /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml[2]. Also attached the ImageMagick log[3] when this happens.

Server: CentOS 6.9, 8-core CPU, 32G Memory, 500G Disk

[1] convert one-page.psd -flatten -thumbnail 1280x1280 thumbnail.jpeg

[2]

```
<policymap>
  <policy domain="resource" name="temporary-path" value="/data01/imagemagick-tmp"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="2GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="map" value="4GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="disk" value="50GiB"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="thread" value="1"/>
  <policy domain="resource" name="throttle" value="5"/>
</policymap>
```

[3]

```
<event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Cache convert[1944]: cache.c/ClonePixelCacheRepository/842/Cache
  Memory => Memory</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Resource convert[1944]: resource.c/RelinquishMagickResource/1069/Resource
  Memory: 70224B/1.33725GiB/2GiB</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Cache convert[1944]: cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3778/Cache
  open One-page.psd[0] (Heap Memory, 418x14x4 93632B)</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDLayer/1493/Coder
      reading data for channel 1</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDChannelRLE/1158/Coder
        layer data is RLE compressed</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDLayer/1493/Coder
      reading data for channel 2</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDChannelRLE/1158/Coder
        layer data is RLE compressed</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDLayer/1493/Coder
      reading data for channel 3</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.830 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDChannelRLE/1158/Coder
        layer data is RLE compressed</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.840 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ApplyPSDLayerOpacity/393/Coder
    applying layer opacity 22873</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.840 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDImage/2374/Coder
    reading the precombined layer</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:37+08:00 3:45.840 14.550u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDChannelRLE/1158/Coder
        layer data is RLE compressed</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:39+08:00 3:47.980 14.660u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDChannelRLE/1158/Coder
        layer data is RLE compressed</event>
  <event>2019-03-20T18:25:41+08:00 3:50.100 14.770u 7.0.8 Coder convert[1944]: psd.c/ReadPSDChannelRLE/1158/Coder
        layer data is RLE compressed</event>
```

Comment: What's your question? The log shows that you're not hitting your 2GB limit.

Comment: @emcconville From the top command I can observe that the memory usage already hitting to 32G, which is 100% of the available memory. The log just shows what it is processing when it consumes 32G memory.